# How do I hide the bar under icons in the taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-customization

While customizing my desktop I decided I would like to hide the bars under icons:

[image: Taskbar]

I have a few programs like Start10 and 7+ taskbar tweaker installed. I don't think I missed an option to disable it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Credits for this solution goes to Bongo from [this forum post](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/9816-how-get-rid-line-under-taskbar-icons-7.html#post781877).

The following solution only works in windows 10 build 1607 and only if the task bar is at the bottom of the screen.

You can use UxStyle to install a custom theme where there are no lines under the icons in the taskbar:

1. Download the [zip file containing UxStyle and the theme itself](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06966256196720764185)
2. Change your UAC settings in windows 10 to never notify. This is done in control panel under user accounts.
3. Restart
4. Install UxStyle, which is included in the zip file.
5. Restart
6. Move both the NoLine folder and the NoLine.theme file to the windows themes folder, usually located at C:/Windows/Resources/Themes.
7. Double click the NoLine.theme file and you should now have no lines under your open programs icons.
8. Change the UAC settings back to your preffered settings.

The NoLine theme should now be displayed as a theme setting in control panel -> Personalization.

Comment: First of all, Welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but can you please post the pertinent instructions from the method that you referenced?  We hesitate to use hyperlink-only answers, because the original source could disappear at some point in the future.  As a result, the proposed answer would be "broken."  Thanks for your help!

Comment: That makes sense. I have revisited my answer.

Comment: I tried the suggested method and It did not work. Although it did change the color of the line... Not remove it.

Comment: @Random What color does it change to?

Comment: In the picture I posted it is gray. It changed to blue with the theme.

Comment: @Random That is weird. It is gone when I try the suggested solution. Of course it might be, that the color is changed to black, and therefore i can't see it. Maybe it is conflicting with some of your other customisations.

Comment: I got this to work with one additional step: install [UltraUXThemePatcher](http://www.syssel.net/hoefs/software_uxtheme.php) (I don't think UxStyle works any more)

Answer (score 0):

Install [StartIsBack++](http://startisback.com/) Version 2.

> NEW: **Full taskbar skinning! Windows 7** and Windows 8 taskbar styles included

Here you can select the Windows 7 style taskbar in the StartIsBack++ options:

[image]

Here the line is gone.

Comment: I want to remove the line but keep the windows 10 theme. I do not want the Windows 7 one. I tried this and it did not have as much customization as Start10 and they kind of conflicted.

Comment: @Random you are joking. StartIsBack++ blows this Start10 crap away in any terms (functionally and options).

Comment: I only used it briefly while looking for the option. I then removed it as it was conflicting with Start10. I guess I've not given it a chance.